# AIDL Support for Object

Tags: object, for-loop, aidl

I have a scenario in which i run the activity in one process and service in the remote process(since service is long running operation at the background).If i make the service runs withing the same process its holding up the RAM size up to 50MB and keeps increasing. So I have been trying to implement the AIDL approach towards Service as remote process and that doesn't take much RAM size. Where as in AIDL i have support towards the string, int, char-sequence callback and others as per in documentation. But in my case i have get the class object to have control and communicate each other(Activity/Service).

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you need to send a custom class you need to implement for this class interface Parcelable.